# Magento 2: How to add css and js in custom module in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

How to create Magento 2 custom module with include Css and Js ?

Answer (score 32):

I Hope this is useful for You,

add your css file to

**app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/web/css/mycss.css**

**mycss.css**

```
 body{
 background-color:green;

 }
```

add your Js file

**app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/web/js/myjs.js**

**myjs.js:**

```
   require([
    "jquery"
    ], function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Hello");
    });
   });
```

Reference:
http://webkul.com/blog/magento2-how-to-add-css-and-js-file-in-module/
http://www.webspeaks.in/2016/03/how-to-add-css-and-js-in-magento-2-custom-module.html

Then add css and Js File to Your layout File.

**app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/test_index_index.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
       <head>
          <css src="Vendor_Module::css/mycss.css" />
          <script src="Vendor_Module::js/myjs.js"/>
     </head> 
       <body>
         <referenceContainer name="content">
              <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\class" template="Vendor_Module::class.phtml"/>
         </referenceContainer>  
     </body> 
    </page>
```

Remove this folder

```
 rm -rf var/cache/*
 rm -rf var/page_cache/*
```

Remove pub/static

```
rm -rf pub/static/*
```

or

```
 If throw any error, via remove pub/static in terminal,

 Go to **<Magento root Dir>** via file manager the **remove pub/static**  directory.

 not using terminal to remove **pub/static** **folder**.
```

Next generate Static Content:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Or

```
php   bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Now, try, Its worked for me.

Comment: Thank for your reply Raj. Its worked for me....

Comment: You forgot to put `php` before `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy `


So, last command is: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy `

Comment: @WaPoNe  I use  `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`  its is also works , i think windows only use  `php  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: @Rajkumar.E when you try to call your css/js, you have to specify the vendorName_moduleName also before css/js name: `<css src="vendorName_moduleName::css/mycss.css" />` and `<script src="vendorName_moduleName::js/myjs.js"/>`

Comment: A word of warning. When running `rm -rf pub/static` for apache users, your `pub/static/.htaccess` file may be removed causing console logs about missing files.

Comment: @Cumbo i update my answers, i did lot of time to remove pub/static using `rm -rf pub/static` , if got issue while remove using rm -rf pub/static command , try to remove vis file manager not using terminal.

Comment: Do i have to run these commands every time i make a change in the js and css files?

Comment: Please use RequireJs to include script.
As well as css tag should be 
`<css src="Module_Name::css/mycss.css"/>`

Comment: Mind as well block: `<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\class" name="some-name" template="Vendor_Module::class.phtml"/>`

Answer (score 8):

**Try this**

```
Create the view/<area>/layout/default.xml file in your module folder, which can be app/code/Df/Core, for instance.

Replace <area> with adminhtml or frontend
```

default.xml should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   layout="admin-1column"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"
>
   <head>
       <link src="Df_Core::core.js"/>
       <css src="Df_Core::core.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
   <body/>
</page>

put the core.js and core.css files to the view/<area>/web folder.
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. i will check and let you know..