# Bundle Products Not Showing Summary

Tags: magento2, products, bundle

No Summary is getting generated when configuring a bundled product on my Magento installation. I have been debugging the `/vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/web/js/product-summary.js` file but all I can tell is that it is getting fired on each event. I can get the file to log the names of the products added to the bundle ect just nothing is added to the bundle summary.

The bundle-summary container is present and there are no errors in the console. Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

I had used a script found on **Stack Exchange** similar to below to **defer javascript** similar to below:

```
preg_match_all('#(<script.*?</script>)#is', $html, $matches);
$js = '';
foreach ($matches[0] as $value):
    $js .= $value;
endforeach;
$html = preg_replace('#(<script.*?</script>)#is', '', $html);
$html = preg_replace('#</body>#',$js.'</body>',$html);
```

> [Magento 2: How to Solve Defer parsing of JavaScript on CDN?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149383/magento-2-how-to-solve-defer-parsing-of-javascript-on-cdn)

### Issue

This was moving the below script that was needed for the **bundle summary** to work correctly:

```
<script data-template="bundle-summary" type="text/x-magento-template">
                <li>
                    <strong class="label"><%- data._label_ %>:</strong>
                    <div data-container="options"></div>
                </li>
 </script>
```

### Solution

It is a bit of a messy solution but got around it with a simple **if statement** to stop the moving of these types of script:

```
preg_match_all('#(<script.*?</script>)#is', $html, $matches);
$js = '';
foreach ($matches[0] as $value):
if (strpos($value, 'type="text/x-magento-template"') === false) {
    $js .= $value;
    $html = str_replace($value, '', $html);
}
endforeach;
$html = preg_replace('#</body>#',$js.'</body>',$html);
```