# Adding css to a module in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, css, xml, custom

I am trying to add custom CSS without creating a theme and these are my steps.

**Step 1**
I create a `mycss.css` file

```
body{
 background-color:green;

 }
```

and this is the path

> app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/web/css/mycss.css

**Step 2**
I create a `test_index_index.xml` file with this content

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
     <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
       <head>
          <css src="vendor_Module::css/mycss.
     </head> 
       <body>
         <referenceContainer name="content">
              <block class="vendor\Module\Block\class" template="vendor_Module::class.phtml"/>
         </referenceContainer>  
     </body> 
    </page>
```

Which is located at

> app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/test_index_index.xml

Reference [Magento 2: How to add css and js in custom module in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132418/magento-2-how-to-add-css-and-js-in-custom-module-in-magento-2/132433#132433)

Unfortunately, on my frontend nothing changes. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Why you just can't create a custom theme? It would make development a lot easier.

Comment: It was successful with the theme but I wanted to try to decrease the files and the complexity only to a css and a xml file because the only needed change is to margin a text field with 10 px.

Comment: Sooner or later you will need to do some more changes. There is no project where all you need is 10px margin.
Also in my opinion, themes adds some clarity not complexity.

Answer (score 1):

**test_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
        <head>
            <css src="Vendor_Module::css/mycss.css"/>
        </head> 
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Class" template="Vendor_Module::file.phtml"/>
            </referenceContainer>  
        </body> 
    </page>
```

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: Thank you for the response!
Question: for xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="should I put my path leading up to that file and shouldn't Vendor be with a lower case?

Comment: Look my update please, more information about xml schema validation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/XSD-XML-validation.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Create **_module.less** file inside `Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\css\source\` and write below code inside the file:

> ```
> & when(@media-common = true) {
>   // write here your css 
> }
> ```

Then run below commands:

1. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
2. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
3. `php bin/magento cache:flush`